# Нумерация строк ComboBox WPF

Tags: wpf

Здравствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой что проверенный алгоритм нумерации строк в ListBox не корректно работает с ComboBox. А именно при активации выпадающего списка строки пронумерованны правильно, но у выбранного элемента нумерация строки не отображается в ComboBox.

ВАРИАНТ 1 через конвертер

```
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}}, Converter={StaticResource RowNumberConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="1" Text="{Binding}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("RowNumberConverter");

        if (value is ListViewItem)
        {
            var item = (ListViewItem)value;
            var listView = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item) as ListView;
            int index = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item);
            return index.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        if (value is ComboBoxItem)
        {
            var item = (ComboBoxItem)value;
            var comboBox = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item) as ComboBox;
            int index = comboBox.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item);
            return index.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

вариант 2 через AlternationCount

```
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="1"
              MinWidth="100"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              AlternationCount="{Binding Path=Signals.Count,
                                         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Signals}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedIndex,
                                     UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">

        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplatedParent.(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="1" Text="{Binding}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Не 1 не 2 вариант не работают. В отладчике посмотрел ход выполнения Конвертера, и он выполняется только при отрисовке списка при первом обращении, нумерует строки, при принятии какого либо значения конвертер не срабатывает, т.к. не срабатывает Binding (не меняется ComboBoxItem). Прошу помочь как отображать в выбранном элементе ComboBox номер строки.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте сделать просто. Если индекс элемента важен, поместите его в VM и привяжитесь к нему.

Comment: Т.е. например сделать не список а словарь, и Key в словаре заполнять при реализации порядковым номером?  в текущем примере просто так сделать, у меня реальный пример сложнее там конечная коллекция для Байндинга находится в модели, еще одним  ComboBox -ом я выбираю нужную строчку в словаре, а второй ComboBox  отражает пронумерованный список который находится в Value словаря. Да и хотелось бы чтобы View это разруливало, независимо от коллекции на которую привязываюсю

Comment: Скорее всего VladD имел ввиду, что  индекс поместить в объект, который вы показываете в комбобоксе, в вашем случае в те объекты что лежат в Value словаря.

Comment: Но ведь для модели это не надо, получается я Model подстраиваю под View, для этого есть ViewModel. или еще лучшие View сама знает как пронумеровать строки.

Comment: @Aldmi: Нет, это не модель, а VM. Вы ведь не биндитесь к **модельным** объектам, да?

Comment: Ну основная коллекция для байндинга через мапинг  находится во вью модели, но в основной коллекции есть вложенные коллекции (Value словаря) вот они биндятся получается из модели. первый комбобокс выбирает элемент словаря а второй комбобкос конечный элемент из списка находящегося в Value.

Comment: @Aldmi: Не-не, это неправильно. Вы биндитесь к модели, и понятно, что в ней есть лишь те данные, которые интересны модели. Так что правильное решение — не биндиться к модели :) Подумаю над workaround'ом.